# Composer update error while trying to install ccdn-forum-bundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, installation, bundle, composer-php

first of all I would like to say that I'm relatively new to symfony and I work with Netbeans.

My first problem occurs when I'm trying to install ccdn-forum-bundle like it's said here:

https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNForumForumBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/install.md

When I try to update-dev with composer I get this error:

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
  "git" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It occurs when composer is trying to update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle and when I try to run my project I get this error from symfony:

ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MonologBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalInternoHUPR\app\AppKernel.php line 14. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

I tryed to fix it by running install dev in composer, but then I get this other one:

Fatal error: Class 'Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\app\AppKernel.php on line 23
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to install git

Comment: But git is intregrated on netbeans, actually I hadn't any problems installing bundles before, anyway I'll try installing git out of netbeans.

Comment: Allready installed git and i've got the same error: - Updating friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dev-master (3969d7f => 094bea6)


                                                                 
  [RuntimeException]                                             
  Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no  
  "git" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,        
  programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use netbeans, and install the bundle directly from the prompt
First check if git is correctly installed

```
 git –version
```

Then run

```
php composer.phar update
```

If that didn’t work for you, I suggest making a fresh install using `--prefer-dist` option

```
php composer.phar install --prefer-dist
```

Comment: Well, git is installed version: 1.9.4.msysgit.1 but when I try to update composer.phar I get this error: "Could not open input file: composer.phar". Anyway let me tell you that I'm not used to work with git.

Comment: I'm now reading a tutorial about it, and I'll keep trying. Thanks for helping

Comment: I't seems that wasn't the last of my troubles, I've got another:   1/1 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to HUPR\UserBundle\Listener\LoginListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalInternoHUPR\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1703 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalInternoHUPR\src\HUPR\UserBundle\Listener\LoginListener.php line 27